# Accesing Values From One Form on Another

Tags: forms, delphi, translation, delphi-2010, caption

Im trying to build in a language switch into one of my programs.

Where the user selects a language and in runtime the app gets translated. I sort of got this working in a small test project. BUT only when the forms are auto created, which i dont want.

the way the forms get created is the following:

SideNote: Most of my forms are fsMDIChild forms.

```
ParametersForm := TParametersForm.Create(Self);  //(consider this the mainform for now)
```

On ParametersForm I have

```
procedure TParametersForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ResourceStringsDM.ParametersF; //(consider this the second form)
end;
```

this Datamodule houses the captions for ParametersForm.

```
procedure TResourceStringsDM.ParametersF;
 begin
   with ParametersForm do
   begin
    bsSkinLabel1.Caption := 'Execute Nieuwefacturen';
    bsSkinLabel2.Caption := 'Execute Viewfacturen';
   end;
 end;
```

I have added ResourceStringsDM to the implementation uses of ParametersForm and ParametersForm to the interface uses of ResourceStringsDM.

This all above gives me an access violation cause in the procedure where it sets the captions uses ParametersForm (var name of the form i want to translate) but at that moment this var is nil. Prolly cause it isnt done creating the form yet and hasnt filled in the form var.

The only way i got this all working was by using

```
 Application.CreateForm(TParametersForm, ParametersForm);
```

But I want to avoid this after reading about it, and that you should only use this on your mainform. Also it doesnt handle passing parameters very well.

Does anyone of you fine people have any hints or tips / help to get me access to the captions of form 1 from form 2?

i probably forgot tons of info you guys need. just tell me and ill add it in.

Comment: Why not do it properly, using actual `resourcestring` constants and the built-in [language support](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Translation_Manager_in_the_IDE) instead of trying to reinvent the wheel yourself? (And just FYI: SO is a site for professionals; "prolly" isn't an actual word in the English language, and neither is "u". You're not texting your buddies here. Please use real words.)

Comment: wow mr grumpy.....fixed the language for your entertainment. But the answer you gave is not what i asked.

Comment: I didn't give you an answer - I posted a comment asking a common-sense question, to make sure you were aware that there was already the capability to do this without all of the kludgy stuff you're adding to try and do it yourself. As far as being "grumpy", this is a professional site for professional people, and it's perfectly reasonable to expect you to use actual vocabulary here. If it's not worth the trouble to you to write a clear question using real words, why should it be worth our effort to provide you with help solving your problems using our time?

Comment: @Bram It's not just for our entertainment. I have no idea what 'prolly' is supposed to mean without looking it up. So it diminishes *your* chance of people taking the time to answer you. It's your job to reread your questions when posting them and making sure that you have made as easy as possible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

In an "MDI Application" template (file->new-other->...>, neither MDI childs are auto created nor the child form's unit contains the global form reference. There's a reason for this, more than one instance of a child form should be able to run at the same time. When you have two instances of the same child for instance, which one will the form reference hold?

Anyway, it is of course possible to not to use this design, but then if you don't use the construct you mention in the question, you're responsible for assigning the instance to the reference yourself. So either do it (which I don't recommend):

```
procedure TParametersForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ParametersForm := Self; 
 ResourceStringsDM.ParametersF; //(consider this the second form)
end;
```

or better, pass the instance to the function in your data module so that it can work on it:

```
procedure TResourceStringsDM.ParametersF(ParametersForm: TParametersForm);
 begin
   with ParametersForm do
   begin
    bsSkinLabel1.Caption := 'Execute Nieuwefacturen';
    ...
```

```
procedure TParametersForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ResourceStringsDM.ParametersF(Self); //(consider this the second form)
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sertac Akyuz! i will try this when i got some time this weekend